# Testing two strings with ginkgo trouble

Tags: testing, go, ginkgo

First of all I want to tell you that I’m very new at go and that I came from Python. Having saying that than I can continue with my problem. I’m having the following trouble:

```
cacciald@cacciald-Lenovo-G470:~/workspace/gopath/src/github.com/lcacciagioni/bosh_web_console/executor$ go test
Running Suite: Executor Suite
=============================
Random Seed: 1409854483
Will run 1 of 1 specs

• Failure [0.005 seconds]
Executor
/home/cacciald/workspace/gopath/src/github.com/lcacciagioni/bosh_web_console/executor/executor_test.go:21
  Should execute a command [It]
  /home/cacciald/workspace/gopath/src/github.com/lcacciagioni/bosh_web_console/executor/executor_test.go:20

  Expected
      <string>: Hello World

  to be equivalent to
      <string>: Hello World

  /home/cacciald/workspace/gopath/src/github.com/lcacciagioni/bosh_web_console/executor/executor_test.go:19
------------------------------

Summarizing 1 Failure:

[Fail] Executor [It] Should execute a command 
/home/cacciald/workspace/gopath/src/github.com/lcacciagioni/bosh_web_console/executor/executor_test.go:19

Ran 1 of 1 Specs in 0.006 seconds
FAIL! -- 0 Passed | 1 Failed | 0 Pending | 0 Skipped --- FAIL: TestExecutor (0.01 seconds)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/lcacciagioni/bosh_web_console/executor       0.019s
```

Here is the code:

```
// Package executor will provide a way to execute console commands in our
// Operative System.-
package executor

import (
        "bytes"
        "log"
        "os/exec"
)

func Runner(command, params string) string {
        cmd := exec.Command(command, params)
        var out bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &out
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        return out.String()
}
```

And here is my simple test:

```
package executor_test

import (
        . "github.com/lcacciagioni/bosh_web_console/executor"

        . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
        . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
)

var _ = Describe("Executor", func() {
        var (
                cmd    string
                params string
        )

        It("Should execute a command", func() {
                cmd = "echo"
                params = "Hello World"
                Expect(Runner(cmd, params)).To(BeEquivalentTo(params))
        })
})
```

If some can tell me why this is not working that will be great!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `\n` of `echo`.

this works fine:

```
 var _ = Describe("Executor", func() {
             var (
                     cmd    string
                     params string
             )

             It("Should execute a command", func() {
                     cmd = "echo"
                     params = "Hello World"
                     Expect(Runner(cmd, params)).To(BeEquivalentTo(params + "\n"))
             })
     })
```

Comment: Other side comment: rather than state the types, use short variable declarations.  e.g. *cmd* can be defined with **cmd := "echo"**.